# Django Admin - filter inline options by 3rd Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

### Use-case:

There are 3 Models:

1. User
2. Division
3. Office

The relations are:

- An Office is always connected to one Division.
- A User can be a member of various Divisions, and work for various offices.

I want to create an inline for my User admin page, under the Office field. However I would like to populate the inline options with Offices that belong only to Divisions that the user is part of.

### Code:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Division(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)


class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

```py
class OfficeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  # I assume I should change it here, but I don't know how to filter accordingly.
  office = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Office.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")

class OfficeInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Office
  form = OfficeAdminForm

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [OfficeInline]

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category)
```